# Does CorePlot support zooming and panning of Charts?

Tags: iphone, ios, charts, core-plot

We are using Coreplot to draw Charts in our IOS application, however we can't make the charts support zooming or panning. We are still running the application on the emulator didn't install on a real device yet because we are waiting for the Developer ID from Apple. Does any one know if Coreplot support these features?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**, Core Plot supports zooming and panning.

You have to set the `allowsUserInteraction` bool of your plot space to `YES`.

See [this link](http://florent.clairambault.fr/downloads/iPhone/core-plot-doc/interface_c_p_plot_space.html#a6c8fcf5db07950c3e84304180e9cd9d6) for more information.

Also, if you want to test zooming in the simulator, you can do this by pressing the *alt* button and click+drag with your mouse. Panning is just normal click+drag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have an idea if that works on the emulator?

Comment: Thanks :), just to refresh my mind, you zoom in on the simulator by double clicking, and zoomn out by right clicking using the mouse ?

Comment: @HassanMokdad: no, that does not seem to work (at least in my app). But the other ways should work perfectly fine. Double tapping might work on the device though. I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: @HassanMokdad: I just tried to zoom by double tapping on the device; it did not work.